# How to install an OS using external Hard Disk?

Tags: windows-7

I have 500gb hard disk but full used, now i want to add an external hard disk and want to install an OS(windows 7) in this hard disk. Is it possible ? If YES then HOW?

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful for people who want to run windows on external Hard Disk:
http://lifehacker.com/how-to-run-a-portable-version-of-windows-from-a-usb-dri-1565509124

There is a tool called [WinToUSB](http://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/index.html) that allows you to install Windows 7 to an external hard drive or a USB flash drive and run Windows 7 from that drive. And you only need a few simple things to make this work.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this.  Basically, the process is simple: boot the Windows installation disc.  When the installer asks where Windows should be installed to, the installer will show some options.  Choose the eternal disk.

The process might get to be a bit more complicated, because you might need some drivers to install.  The installer should have an option to allow you to install drivers (perhaps by pressing a certain key while it starts up).  If this is necessary, you'll probably need to get drivers that come from the manufacturer of the external drive.  Details on that can vary, particularly among different manufacturers.  (Since this question did not identify which drive is being used, specific details are not provided.  I suggest checking the manufacturer's website.)  However, I probably wouldn't bother researching this before just checking if the Windows installer auto-detects the drive just fine.  If so, you probably don't need to worry about manually loading any drivers, so just choose the drive you want.